# Glitched view in viewport when using Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

For some obscure reasons, Cycles has been making my viewport glitch for two days.
I run Blender on a Macbook Pro M2 14.9" 2023.

Here's a link to a screen capture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HUMS-1gH-c6z6Dxa55IKkbLT0O1OQHHN/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance

Comment: A screenshot of the glitch would help a lot, not everyone can open the blendfile when visiting your question, and it might not even be needed or replicable on our side

Comment: Please reassure us that you have gone as far as you can to achieve correct configuration.. that you've updated your graphics drivers, the problem arises on more than one file, etc.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: my bad i though the link was a blend file. Could be a driver issue, make sure to update or even try a clean reinstall of your drivers. Otherwise, menu Help > Report A Bug.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure, but I think it might be the specs of your computer. Since your design is complicated and has reflections and such, its really intensive to render especially in real time which is probably causing the glitching. I have experienced similar glitching before (while rendering water which had some reflections but the final render was great). It'll be perfectly fine as a rendered image, though it might take a hot second to actually render. Hope this helps!